# TypeScript icon missing on packages on npm website

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

Hi wrote a package and published it on npm repository and showed icon "**ts**" on the site

[image]

This is package.json with "**ts**" icon "- https://unpkg.com/c2array@0.0.3/package.json

I wrote another package but missing "**ts**" icon

This is package.json mssing "**ts**" icon - https://unpkg.com/@salsan/iscss@1.0.0/package.json

[image: Th]

The different  from these two packages

- Package with "**ts**" icon, files are in [one directory](https://unpkg.com/browse/c2array@0.0.3/dist/)
- Package mssing "**ts**" contain a [sub-directory](https://unpkg.com/browse/@salsan/iscss@1.0.0/dist/)

d.ts file is generated from **tsconfig.json**

```
  "declaration": true,                            
  "declarationMap": true,
```

Any idea for resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the `"types": "PATH TO YOU .D.TS FILE"` in you `package.json`, like

```json
{
  "name": "@salsan/iscss",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "isCss is a Node.js package, return true if input is a valid Cascading Style Sheets",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I need to try your solution, but Why on first package without "types" on package.json,  npm repository showed "ts" icon ?

Comment: That's weird, and it should not, since [GitHub has a blog post saying it will display the badge](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-12-16-npm-displays-packages-with-bundled-typescript-declarations/) only if the `types` (or `typings`) key occurs inside your `package.json`.